# Можно ли написать с RxJava2 оператор if/else с условиями на нескольких уровнях

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Вот есть такой кусок кода

```
if (shouldSearchForCode)
        {
            if (iFilterableObject.getStorageRoomCode().equals(SupergasApplication.getInstance().getUser().getUserName()))
            {
                shouldAdd = true;
            }
            else if (mListener.cbShowOtherEmployeesIsChecked() && mFilteredOtherEmployees != null)
            {
                for (FilterableEmployee filteredOtherEmployee : mFilteredOtherEmployees)
                {
                    if (filteredOtherEmployee != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(filteredOtherEmployee.getStorageRoomCode()) //
                            && iFilterableObject.getStorageRoomCode().equals(filteredOtherEmployee.getStorageRoomCode()))
                    {
                        shouldAdd = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Не могу придумать как тут применить Rx

Попробовал сделать, что то вроде такого

```
Observable.just(shouldSearchForCode)//
        .filter(iBoolean -> iBoolean)//
        .map(//
             iBoolean -> iFilterableObject.getStorageRoomCode().equals(SupergasApplication.getInstance().getUser().getUserName())//
        )//
        .filter(iBoolean -> iBoolean)
```

Но так совсем не получается... Я уже несколько раз сталкиваюсь с очень простой ситуацией, которой не могу понять как имплементируется в Rx2, это когда есть несколько if else условий

Вот как в примере выше

```
if (roomCode.equals(userName))
            {
            }
else if (mListener.cbShowOtherEmployeesIsChecked() && mFilteredOtherEmployees != null)
            {
            }
```

Как это должно работать? Или что то не так